# Is it possible to implement Auth 2.0 in .NET Frame work 2.0 ?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oauth-2.0

I want to implement AUth 2.0 in >net Framework 2.0. While doing authorization i am getting error. 
I have tried below code, but it is giving error "404 Not found".

```
    Dim strExchange = "response_type=authorization_code"
    strExchange += "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:49366/Default.aspx"
    strExchange += "&client_id=********"
    strExchange += "&scope=connectapi.*****"     
    strExchange += "&client_secret=******&grant_type=authorization_code"


    Dim url As String = "https://dev-auth.test.com/connect/authorize?"
    Dim tokenurl As String = "https://dev-auth.test.com/connect/token?"
    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = DirectCast(3072, 
    SecurityProtocolType)      

    Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString(url & strExchange)

    Response.Write(result)
```

Comment: A `404` is generic; server could not find what was requested, user attempts to follow a broken or dead link etc...

Comment: Thank You. Do you have any idea regarding my question? I could not find anything on google, which uses .net 2 and Auth 2.0